# Adding 2 keyvalues to list from JSON object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios4

I want to append 2 key values from JSON object to my list in iPhone app. Below is my code for that,

```
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString *jsonString=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test/json/json_data.php"]];

    id response = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL];

    NSDictionary *feed = (NSDictionary *)response;
    list = (NSArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"fname"];
```

the above code properly displays the value from fname but what do i do if i want to add lname to it. for eg, my object is
[{"fname":"Bill","lname":"Jones"},{"fname":"John","lname":"Jacobs"}]
i want to display names as Bill Jones, John Jacobs and so on in the list. Currently it only displays Bill, John..I tried doing something like @"fname"@lname but it wont work..Can anybody please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observation: the response from the JSON parser is not a dictionary, but an array given the string you pass in. Your code works because `-valueForKey:` is something an array will respond to.  The array sends `-valueforKey:` to each element and builds an array out of the responses.

There are two ways you can do what you want (at least)

1. Iterate through the array explicitly

   ```
   NSMutableArray* list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (id anObject in response)
   {
       [list addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", 
                                                    [anObject objectForKey: @"fName"], 
                                                    [anObject objectForKey: @"lname"]]];
   }
   ```
2. Add a category to NSDictionary

   ```
   @interface NSDictionary(FullName)
   -(NSString*) fullName;
   @end

   @implementation NSDictionary(FullName)

   -(NSString*) fullName
   {
       return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", 
                                          [self objectForKey: @"fName"], 
                                          [self objectForKey: @"lname"]];
   }

   @end
   ```

   Then your existing code changes to

   ```
   list = (NSArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"fullName"];
   ```

Comment: @developer: NSIndexPath does not have a property called row.  Probably your app throws an exception which is why you are not getting any content.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JeremyP..I was able to figure out my problem..Actually the list that I had created locally I changed that to be the instance variable and everything seems to work fine. Thanks for all your help..Everything works perfectly..